# Android Studio how to get data from the Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code and i wanna get the value String (how for example the names for users) from Firebase database in "Usuarios", which contains the users, to put it in the txtName variable.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
private Button btnLogOut;
private int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

private TextView textName;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Usuarios");


public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    TextView textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
}
```

}

Thank you very much, if you could solve this and you would do a great favor :)

[Firebase Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86GYX.png)

Comment: Please add you database structure.

Comment: It's done is edited in the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display all the within those childrens, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usuariosRef = rootRef.child("Usuarios");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usuariosRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
Eric
Julian Ramos
//And so on
```

Comment: Then implement authentication and add each use and his `uid`. That's it. Cheers!